# Detect a Dbgrid is in drag mode

Tags: delphi

How can I detect if a TDbGrid is currently in "drag mode" where a user is dragging a row (or rows) to another component.

I thought that:

```
 if Screen.Cursor = DBGrid.DragCursor then
```

but that seems too brute force.

I could use the OnStartDrag and OnEndDrag events to keep track myself.

I haven't been able to find a property in TDbGrid that indicates the *current* mode.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Dragging`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Dragging) function of the control:

```
if DBGrid1.Dragging then
```